# how to show some time label and hide another time label Wpf toolkit chart

Tags: wpftoolkit, charts

I want to design 2d chart with wpf toolkit that X axis is in time format and Y axis is value depended on time.

every new value generated in 1 second and I want to show all values at 1 day.
in default style x-axis show 1 sec by 1 sec, so labels at x-axis is unreadable.
I want to change chart's style that x-axis's lable have 1 hour diffrence from prev lable.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're addingi a datetime axis on X orientation, try to set the IntervalType and Interval property like this

```
    <chartingToolkit:Chart Name="chart1" >
        <chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
            <chartingToolkit:DateTimeAxis Orientation="X" Interval="1" IntervalType="Hours" />
        </chartingToolkit:Chart.Axes>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

HTH